# pandas DataFrame size inconsistent with windows memory usage

Tags: python, memory, pandas

I am reading in a DataFrame from a hdf5 file:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore('some_file.h5')
df= store['df']
store.close()
```

Using `info` shows:

```
In [11]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 21423657 entries, 0 to 21423656
Data columns (total 5 columns):
date      datetime64[ns]
name      object
length    float64
flag1     object
flag2     object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 980.7+ MB
```

The hdf5 is about 1GB and `df.info()` also shows `memory usage` of about 1GB. However, the physical memory usage from windows task manager shows an increase of over 2GB after reading in the DataFrame. In general I have observed that the actual memory usage from windows task manager is about twice as large as indicated by the `info` function in `pandas`. This extra memory usage is causing MemoryError in later computations. Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? Or does anyone have suggestions on how to go about debugging the "phantom" memory usage?

Comment: Can you show the output of `df.info()`?

Comment: Does this occur immediately after importing the data, or do you do any processing steps before the memory increases?

Comment: The memory usage from windows task manager shows a huge jump immediately after this line: `df= store['df']`.

Comment: The memory usage indicated by pandas is not the total memory *if you have object dtype columns* (which is the case here, and this is indicated with the `+`). See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/faq.html#dataframe-memory-usage

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should've read the doc more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `info` function just calls `numpy.nparray.nbytes` which multiplies the `nitemsize`(the size of the data type, e.g. 8 bytes for int64) and array's length. The problem can come from the `object` data type.

Numpy has rich type system: [Array types and conversions between types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)
, [Data type objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), which you can utilize for higher memory efficiency. You could convert the columns of choice from your data frame, for example from default `float64` to `float32` or `int32` or `unsigned int32` and `object`s to shorter strings with type constructor, e.g. `np.dtype('a25')` — 25-character string, and this, as I've tested, actually frees some memory on my Win7.